# Capturing active window name in Google Chrome in Windows return an error when exiting the Chrome application

Tags: python, google-chrome, window

Using Python to capture the name of the active browser window in Google Chrome (and all other applications), return an error when closing the Google Chrome application. It works while having the application running.

**Error**: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Value'

Below is code being used. I tried to counter the error by adding an If-statement after some Googling. It seems related to that the object is of type None, which I understand as not containing any value. However this did not fix the error.

How would I add code lines to remedy the error? I'd like the program to just continue and not break on this error.

Code except:

```
def get_chrome_url():
    if sys.platform in ['Windows', 'win32', 'cygwin']:
        window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        chromeControl = auto.ControlFromHandle(window)
        edit = chromeControl.EditControl()
        if(edit.GetValuePattern().Value != None):
            return 'https://' + edit.GetValuePattern().Value
    return _active_window_name
```

I was expecting to not get an error after closing main Chrome application. The error remain however. So the line of code:

`if(edit.GetValuePattern().Value != None):`

didn't seem to solve the error.